# search product table data by multiple fields using angular js and web api

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have Product table with 20 columns.I want to search table by multiple field Value. As a input parameters, i have 3 dropdownlist(family,body,series).Based on the selected values product table will be searched. 
**Search might be based on single parameter or multiple parameters**
Here is the Controller

```
[Route("api/KendoCascading/GetProresult/{family}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetProresult(int family)
    {
        using (CrossReferenceTool1Entities eb = new CrossReferenceTool1Entities())
        {
            var query = (from u in eb.Products where (u.PrivateOnly == false && u.SelectionTool == true && u.ProductTypeID == 2 && (u.ProductFamilyID == 11 || u.ProductFamilyID == 12 || u.ProductFamilyID == 58 || u.ProductFamilyID == 59 || u.ProductFamilyID == 92) && u.ProductFMSFamiliesID == family) select u).Distinct().ToList();
            HttpResponseMessage res;
            res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, query);
            return res;
        }
    }
    [Route("api/KendoCascading/GetResFuse/{fuseClass}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetResFuse(string fuseClass)
    {
        using (CrossReferenceTool1Entities fsl = new CrossReferenceTool1Entities())
        {
            var query = (from u in fsl.Products where (u.PrivateOnly == false && u.SelectionTool == true && u.ProductTypeID == 2 && (u.ProductFamilyID == 11 || u.ProductFamilyID == 12 || u.ProductFamilyID == 58 || u.ProductFamilyID == 59 || u.ProductFamilyID == 92) && u.FuseBodyType.Contains(fuseClass)) select u).Distinct().ToList();
            HttpResponseMessage res;
            res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, query);
            return res;
        }
    }
[Route("api/KendoCascading/GetresByfamBody/{family}/{fuseClass}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetresByfamBody(int family, string fuseClass)
    {
        using (CrossReferenceTool1Entities ecl = new CrossReferenceTool1Entities())
        {
            var query = (from u in ecl.Products where (u.PrivateOnly == false && u.SelectionTool == true && u.ProductTypeID == 2 && (u.ProductFamilyID == 11 || u.ProductFamilyID == 12 || u.ProductFamilyID == 58 || u.ProductFamilyID == 59 || u.ProductFamilyID == 92) && u.FuseBodyType.Contains(fuseClass) && u.ProductFMSFamiliesID == family) select u).Distinct().ToList();
            HttpResponseMessage res;
            res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, query);
            return res;
        }
    }
```

calling these methods in angular service

```
this.getProresultByseriesFamily = function (family) {
    var res;
    if (family !== 0) {
        res = $http.get("/api/KendoCascading/GetProresult/" + family);
        return res;
    }
};
//for class dropdown
this.getFuseClassRes = function (fuseClass) {
    var res;
    if (fuseClass !== null) {
        res = $http.get("/api/KendoCascading/GetResFuse/" + fuseClass);
        return res;
    }
};
**this.getresfabody = function (family, fuseClass) {
    var res;
    if (family !== 0 && fuseClass !== "") {
        res = $http.get("/api/KendoCascading/GetresByfamBody/" + family + "/" + fuseClass);
        return res;
    }
};**
```

**angular controller**

```
if(Boolean($scope.SelectedCriteria)) {
            var promise = ngservice.getProresultByseriesFamily($scope.SelectedCriteria);
            promise.then(function (resp) {
                console.log(resp.data);
                $scope.Products = resp.data;
                alert("successful1");
            }, function (err) {
                alert("Falied");
            });
    }
    if (Boolean($scope.FuseModel)){
            var promise = ngservice.getFuseClassRes($scope.FuseModel);
            promise.then(function (resp) {
                $scope.Products = resp.data;
                alert("successful2");
            }, function (err) {
                alert("failed");
            });
    }
if ((Boolean($scope.SelectedCriteria)) && (Boolean($scope.FuseModel)))
    {
        var promise = ngservice.getresfabody($scope.SelectedCriteria, $scope.FuseModel);
        promise.then(function (resp) {
            $scope.Products = resp.data;
            alert("successful");
        }, function (err) {
            alert("Failed");
        });
    }
```

When i select both dropdownlist value(family and class).It is executing IF condition regarding that two models. After that executing again single if conditions also. How to execute only particular if condition. Please help me on this. If any better suggestion to do this search please guide me.

Comment: Instead of having 3 different api's for getting Products, I'd suggest write just a single api using `PredicateBuilder`. In the future, you can even add different selectionCriteria to the same api.

Here is nice post which explain how you could do it: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c42694/dynamic-query-in-linq-using-predicate-builder/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went through that example. So,is it applicable for Web API too. Means I saw some example based on Odata. But I need json data type. So will it be possible to do same? Can you please suggest me  some example on web API and predicate builder. It will be very much helpful for me